# Bash Scripting with xargs to BACK UP files

Tags: linux, echo, xargs, cp

I need to copy a file from multiple locations to the BACK UP directory by retaining its directory structure. For example, I have a file "a.txt" at the following locations /a/b/a.txt /a/c/a.txt a/d/a.txt a/e/a.txt, I now need to copy this file from multiple locations to the backup directory /tmp/backup. The end result should be:

when i list /tmp/backup/a --> it should contain /b/a.txt /c/a.txt /d/a.txt & /e/a.txt.

For this, I had used the command: echo /a/*/a.txt | xargs -I {} -n 1 sudo cp --parent -vp {} /tmp/backup. This is throwing the error "cp: cannot stat '/a/b/a.txt /a/c/a.txt a/d/a.txt a/e/a.txt': No such file or directory"

-I option is taking the complete input from echo instead of individual values (like -n 1 does). If someone can help debug this issue that would be very helpful instead of providing an alternative command.

Comment: Why not use `cp -r` to copy recursively? Or `rsync` to speed it up if the destination is already up to date?

Answer (score 0):

Use `rsync` with the `--relative` (`-R`) option to keep (parts of) the source paths.

I've used a wildcard for the source to match your example command rather than the explicit list of directories mentioned in your question.

```
rsync -avR /a/*/a.txt /tmp/backup/
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the backups need to be exactly the same as the originals? In most cases, I'd prefer a little compression. `[tar](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html)` does a great job of bundling things including the directory structure.

```
tar cvzf /path/to/backup/tarball.tgz /source/path/
```

`tar` can't *update* compressed archives, so you can skip the compression

```
tar uf /path/to/backup/tarball.tar /source/path/
```

This gives you versioning of a sort, as if only updates changed files, but keeps the before and after versions, both.

If you have time and cycles and still want the compression, you can decompress before and recompress after.